# ACL Permissions - Determine between Security Group and User

Tags: powershell, acl

Ok, our office has a rule that individual users can't be added to folders, but, well, over the years with such a big organization it has happened all over the network.

I am playing with powershell and have created a simple script that generates a permission map of the entire SAN but I am hoping to tweak the script to display all individual users that have permissions to a folder. Has anyone done something like this? I've been googling/playing around for the last couple hours looking for a way to differentiate between the two, but at this time no luck...

Answer (score 0):

A trustee is a trustee is a trustee. There is no inherent difference between a "group" trustee and a "user" trustee. To distinguish between them, you need to either

- build a list of valid users and check for all trustees that are contained in it, or
- build a list of valid groups and check for all trustees that are not contained in it.